# Laravel mix put all js code inside app.js

Tags: laravel, webpack

I wonder if its possible to put everything inside the app.js file? I have a lot of files that I wont touch for a long time so I dont need to worrie about cache.

Right now I am doing this in my webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js') .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css') .scripts([ 'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js', 'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js' ], 'public/js/all.js');
```

This will make two JS files: **app.js** and **all.js**. What I now want to do is to combine those files into one big file app.js. Is this possible with?:

`mix.babel(['app.js', 'all.js'], 'app.js');` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put everything in the `js()` method and take advantage of it (as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#working-with-scripts)):

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js'
], 'public/js/all.js');
```

Try checking [the documentation from the Laravel Mix repository on Github](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/mixjs.md#javascript). There are some useful information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

To combine .js files use mix.combine:

```
mix.combine(['one.js', 'two.js'], 'merged.js');
```

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/concatenation-and-minification.md